# Add data to recyclerView from Sqlite in realtime?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, tcp, android-recyclerview

I've made an app that is receiving some data from a **TCP Client** to my **TCP Server** that store the data in **SQlite DB**, and actually i've made a `recyclerView` where to visualize all that data but now my *issue* is what i'm trying like 2 weeks to refresh the `recyclerView` in real Time, i mean if a **TCP Client** will send a new package to my **TCP Server** and if **i'm in the activity with the** `recyclerView` the data have to be added **dynamically.**
I will also accept any type of ***tips and suggestions*** on how to improve my app.
Actually it's my **1st** app i've ever created in Android.

[HERE](https://github.com/UAiGorMan/SelfM) you can find my `Server`(TCPServer),`RecyclerViewAdapter`,`Adapter`(constructor),`allert.java`(class where i invoke the `RecyclerViewAdapter`.

*Hope someone will be able to help me and ill be very grateful.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending broadcast method. Here are the steps :

1. Make a  inner class that extends BroadcastReceiver in your activity.

   ```
   private class ExampleBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       //do stuffs here, e.g. getting extras from intent
   }
   ```
2. Declare a instance of the class outside any methods.

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

       private ExampleBroadcastReceiver exampleBroadcastReceiver;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           //stuffs
       }

   }
   ```
3. Override onResume method. Initialize the instance you just made in this method. Then, register it with a intent-filter. This will make sure that your broadcast receiver ready when user open the activity.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
       filter.addAction("com.example.MainActivity");   
       exampleBroadcastReceiver = new ExampleBroadcastReceiver();
       LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(exampleBroadcastReceiver, filter);
   }
   ```
4. Override onPause method and unregister your receiver.

   ```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        try {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(exampleBroadcastReceiver);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
       if (!e.getMessage().contains("Receiver not registered")) {
           // unexpected, re-throw
           throw e;

    }
   ```
5. Make sure you use ArrayList for dynamic data.
6. Whenever you receive data from server, after you store them in your database, send a broadcast with extras contains data you want to display in your activity.

**EDITED**

I registered the receiver using an instance of LocalBroadcastManager.

Comment: What is `updateReceiver = new UpdateReceiver();`? and also in Server.java for send a broadcast with extras i just have to pass the data by intent?

Comment: @I.Mytyuk Sorry, the UpdateReceiver is a class I use in my project, I copied it here but forgot to change it. Yes, put the data you want to show using extras. There's something I also forgot, it's better to register the receiver using `LocalBroadcastManager` if the receiver is supposed to only receive intent from your own application. I've edited my answer.